# How to show all error messages on the same submit click (form)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Here we go for my first ever question on Stackoverflow !!!
I am a JS student for 2 weeks....

I searched on the forum but doesn't find anything, I think because I don't really know how to formulate my question.

So, I have a html form which I validate all inputs with some JS.
When the form is empty and user clic on submit button, the first error message on the first input is shown but nothing to the others empty inputs. When the first is OK but not the second, the error message appear on the second input, but nothing on the third, etc etc...

What I try is, when a user clic on the submit button and all the form is empty, all messages of all empty inputs are shown.
I have no idear how I can do that.

Can you give me an advice ?

Thank you all !!!

A last thing, I only can use vanilla javascript to do this !

Here is my code:

````
function editNav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

// DOM Elements
const modalbg = document.querySelector(".bground");
const modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-btn");
const formData = document.querySelectorAll(".formData");

//VARIABLES
const xButton = document.querySelector(".close"); // Bouton croix
// const subButton = document.querySelector(".btn-submit"); //Bouton submit

let firstName = document.querySelector("#firstName"); // Prénom
let lastName = document.querySelector("#lastName"); // Nom
let email = document.querySelector("#email"); //Email
let birthdate = document.querySelector("#birthdate"); //Date de naissance
let nbrTournaments = document.querySelector("#quantity"); //Nbr tournois
let myForm = document.querySelector("#reserve"); //Formulaire complet
let emailError = document.querySelector(".mail-error"); //Erreur email
let firstNameError = document.querySelector('.firstname-error'); //Erreur prénom
let lastNameError = document.querySelector('.lastname-error'); //Erreur nom
let tournamentError = document.querySelector('.tournament-error'); //Erreur nbr tournois
let radioError = document.querySelector(".radio-button-error");//Erreur checkbox
let radioButton = document.forms[0].location;//Radio button
let birthdateError = document.querySelector(".birthdate-error");
let checkboxError = document.querySelector(".checkbox-error");
let checkbox = document.querySelector("#checkbox1");
let errorMsg = document.querySelectorAll(".errormsg");
let allInput = document.forms[0].input; //Tous les inputs
//REGEXP
let emailRegExp = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
let dateRegExp =/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/

//MODAL
// launch modal event
modalBtn.forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener("click", launchModal));
// close modal event
xButton.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
// launch modal form
function launchModal() {
  modalbg.style.display = "block";
}
// close modal form
function closeModal() {
  modalbg.style.display = "none";
}

//VALIDATION FORMULAIRE
function validate() {
  //Validation formulaire entier
  if (allInput == null) {
    return false
  }
  // Validation Prenom
  if (firstName.value == "") {
    firstNameError.innerHTML = "Votre prénom doit contenir 2 caractères ou plus.";
    return false;
  }
  // Validation Nom
  if (lastName.value == "") {
    lastNameError.innerHTML = "Votre nom doit contenir 2 caractères ou plus!";
    return false;
  }
  //Validation Mail
  let testEmail = emailRegExp.test(email.value);
  if (testEmail === false) {
    emailError.innerHTML = "Veuillez saisir une adresse email valide.";
    return false;
  }
  //Validation Date de naissance
  let testDate = dateRegExp.test(birthdate.value);
  if (testDate === false) {
    birthdateError.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer votre date de naissance.";
    return false;
  }
  //Validation nombre de tournois
  if (nbrTournaments.value === "") {
    tournamentError.innerHTML = "Veuillez entrer un nombre";
    return false;
  }
  //Validation Radio Button
  //Boucle vérifier
  let valid = false;
for(let i = 0; i < radioButton.length; i++) {
  if (radioButton[i].checked){
    valid = true;
    break;
  }
}
if(valid) {
  radioError.innerHTML = ""
} else {
  radioError.innerHTML = "Veuillez choisir une option";
  return false;
}
//Validation Checkbox
  if (checkbox.checked === false) {
    checkboxError.innerHTML = "Veuillez lire et valider les conditions."
    return false;
  }
  alert('Merci ! Votre réservation a bien été envoyée.')
  return true;
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your validation function finds an error it returns `false`, which breaks off the validation function then and there. So only the first error is detected and displayed.
You should remove these `return false` statements and only return false at the end if there was 1 or more errors.

Comment: Thank you, it work well now with your advices.
I deleted all the "return false"  that stopped the execution and add this line at the end, just before "return true" :
```if ((!valid||!testDate||!testEmail||!checkbox.checked)||(lastName.value === "")||(firstName.value === "")||(nbrTournaments.value === "")) {
  return false;```

Comment: Just a small suggestion to make your code more readable: set a variable `$valid = true` in the beginning of the script, then wherever you originally had the return false statements you set this variable to `false`. If no error is detected, then `$valid` will still be `true` in the end, and if any 1 or more errors happened it will be `false` at the end. That makes your if clause simpler at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For validating simple form, you just need to know :

1. how you make require

   - select control (sorry to long to explain)
   - radio control (sorry to long to explain)
   - checkbox control (sorry to long to explain)
   - input control (see below example)
2. style css disabled form submit button or input  (see below example)
3. read doc about 2 events  (see below example)

   - [w3school oninput event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)
   - [w3school oninvalid event](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ev_oninvalid.asp)

For help a small example :

```html
<form onSubmit="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="username" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(event)" oninput="InvalidMsg(event)" required>
  <div>
    <input type="paswword" placeholder="password" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(event)" oninput="InvalidMsg(event)" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required>
    <small>The password format is 5 digits length</small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">valider</button>
</form>
```

```js
const InvalidMsg = function(e) {
  const elem = e.target
  elem.classList.remove('error')
  elem.classList.remove('success')
  if (!elem.validity.valueMissing && !elem.validity.patternMismatch) {
     elem.classList.add('success')
  } else {
    elem.classList.add('error')
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert('ok')
  })
})
```

```css
input{
  outline: none;
  border:solid 1px gray;
}
.error{
  border-left: solid 3px red;
}
.success{
  border-left: solid 3px green;
}
form:invalid button[type="submit"], form:invalid input[type="submit"] {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Key here is do not return validation success right after first field validation. Complete all fields validation.

Check below stackblitz solution for you. And accept the answer if it works.
(Solution is in angular. However, you can easily copy paste to javascript)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-submit-simple-bs2xen?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts